# Help me create an iPad photos-like gallery with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, ipad, photo-gallery, jquery-isotope

[image]

I've been playing around with a gallery similar to that of the [iPad's photos app](http://www.apple.com/ipad/built-in-apps/photos.html), where you have thumbnails neatly stacked and upon clicking(touching) they fly out in a grid layout. If one gallery/stack is already open when you click another stack, the photos should pile up at their original position before the next set animates out.

I though something like [Isotope](http://isotope.metafizzy.co) would be helpful here, but I'm having a real hard time making it stop overwriting itself. Also, I can't quite figure out how to make it seem as if the thumbnails fly out from the "cover image".

I put a simplified version of [what I've got so far on JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Ahrengot/5dMrx/).

**Any help is greatly appreciated**. I feel like I'm in a little over my head here :)

My question is: **how do i make it seem as if the thumbnails fly out from the "cover image"?**

Comment: here is ur fiddle without the annoying start: http://jsfiddle.net/maniator/5dMrx/42/

Comment: This doesn't sound like a question at all. Please reformat it as a specific question

Comment: @Ahrengot -- i updated ur fiddle in the OP

Comment: @Eran -- i bolded the question in the OP

Comment: Please correct JSFiddle link -> http://jsfiddle.net/5dMrx/

Comment: I saw this question and made this: http://jsfiddle.net/minitech/v9dNE/ if it helps. You'd have to handle the album rearranging though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could have an absolutely positioned DIV with a full-size image inside.

Initially, position the div and scale the image such that it perfectly overlaps with the thumbnail.

Then, animate the location and size of both to bring them to the center of the screen at the size you want.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback guys. Sorry for not being clear enough in my question before.

I've updated the fiddle-link, and I think I might be able to reach my goal from here. 

Thanks a bunch!

Comment: If my answer helped, would you might clicking the checkmark under the vote buttons to mark it as an answer?

Comment: Sure no problem. Still new to this site :)